# Set variable globally

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, global-variables

I have a problem I can't make it work. I want to have a global variable that is set when an Admin press a button. I made the button action, but can't make my variable to change and I don't know why.

So when an Admin click a button, it changes the value of the variable for all the app, because I want my views to show up depending on that variable.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to create some sort of maintenance mode? If so laravel has a built in system for that

Comment: How are you trying to achieve this ? Can we see some code ?

Comment: In fact, I decided to create a config table in my database and send that 1 row table to the Controller.php and share it to all my views.

Comment: Would you post the code you used to create this table and the portion of controller.php that made the data sharable? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could manage to set up a global variable but that I will encourage you not to do it.
If you want to change that variable and access it's value on the next requests you should rely on the [Session API.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session)

To set the variable (From Laravel docs):

```
// Via a request instance...
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');

// Via the global helper...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

and to read it:

```
//Via a request instance...
$value = $request->session()->get('key');
//Via the global helper...
$value = session('key');
```

You can even specify a default value to be returned in case the key you want to retrieve doesn't exist:

```
$value = session('key', 'default');
```

Comment: I have tried this but I needed it to stay more than the next request. In fact, I decided to create a config table in my database and send that 1 row table to the Controller.php and share it to all my views.

Comment: The session data won't last a request but the whole session time. In case you' re using cookies it should be until it expires.
About that table, if that variable is more a user config that should remain set through sessions rather than during a particular one, then I'm with you.

Comment: It is really a variable I need everywhere in my app, because some views will depend on that variable. ;)